# Connection Elastic Search to R

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect R  to elastic

> 

```
elastic::connect(
  es_host = "https://search.imobuyer.com/elasticsearch/admin/",
  es_transport_schema = "https",
  es_user = "normalizador",
  es_pwd = "******"
)
```

The folowing error message:

> out <- elastic::Search(index = "realties")

```
Error: 404 - no such index
ES stack trace:

  type: index_not_found_exception
  reason: no such index
  resource.type: index_or_alias
  resource.id: :9200
  index_uuid: _na_
  index: :9200
```

Comment: in the current version of `elastic` the `connect` function shouldn't be doing any HTTP requests. what function throws that error? . I assume `Search`?

Comment: i update the question, Yest the function Search

Comment: thanks. are you sure that url is the right one? the `/admin` at the end looks suspicuous, or is that just a fake url? one thing to do is `connect(errors = "complete")` to get more error info, and also when you get the error run `traceback()` and see if there's any info pointing to where that error occurs

Comment: UPdate again !!!

Comment: try `z=Search(index = "realties", config = httr::verbose())` and you should see the actual URL that's sent - make sure that url is correct. i suspect it's not the right url - OR the `index_not_found_exception` could mean you are at the right base url but the index just doesn't exist